# Drive/animate smoke size according to particle lifetime?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

Is it possible to set the size of particles in the smoke simulation settings according to particle lifetime?

[image]

E.g. to make particles emit less smoke over time and gradually fade away, rather than suddenly disappearing.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible at moment as size affects all particles together.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to change the size of a particle over its lifetime refer to the image and set parameters as described.
 1. use a blend texture
 2. set its mapping to particle/strand
 3. drive the size parameter in the texture properties
[image: Parameters to change]
I used the Blender Internal Engine to set up the texture then switched to Cycles to render.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful, but unfortunately I don't know of a way to get smoke to use individual particle size to influence emission size..